# How do I add more variables to the initialization after I import a module to a class in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to add more variables inside the initialization bracket after importing a module and I get an error,`__init__ takes 3 positional arguments but four were given`. How do I fix this?

```
#Module1
class(first):
  def __init__(self, word, count):
        self.word = word
        self.count = 0

                  
from Module1 import first                                       
class second(first):                                            
   def __init__(self, word, count, option):
     super().__init__(word, count, option)

     def new(word):
         types = type(word)
         if types == str:
            print(word)#if the word is a string print the word
            count += 1#increment the value to 1
option1 = "first attempt"
word1 = "coding"
result = second(word1, 0, option1)
res = result.new(word1)
print(res)
```

I am getting an error`(TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given )`

Comment: You are trying to call `__init__` of `first` with `word, count, option` but it can only accept two arguments. Why do you want to pass `option` to the class that does not accept it?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is a way to add another variable into the initialization bracket instead of having to update the module and add the variable into the module again?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand that sentence at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the attribute *option* to the class *second*:

```
class first(object):
  def __init__(self, word, count):
        self.word = word
        self.count = 0
          
                                    
class second(first):                                           
    def __init__(self, word, count, option):
        super().__init__(word, count)
        self.option = option
     
    def new(self, word):
        types = type(word)
        if types == str:
            print(word) # if the word is a string print the word
            self.count += 1  # increment the value to 1
           
            
option1 = "first attempt"
word1 = "coding"
result = second(word1, 0, option1)
res = result.new(word1)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is that `second` needs an additional member variable. This is one of the patterns available through OOP, called `"programming by difference"`. You just need to get `second` to do this:

```py
class second(first):                                            
   def __init__(self, word, count, option):
     super().__init__(word, count)
     self.option = option
```

btw there are other problems with the rest of your code. If you need to, you can ask a separate question about that on stackoverflow.